# Beamer: removing footline isn't working

Tags: beamer, titles, page-numbering

I'm trying to remove the title and frame number from a beamer presentation and I've tried what I found online, but the footnote stays there.

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsemptyter
```

The only one that doesn't show anymore is the navigation symbols. 
I use the Madrid theme.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add a MWE that demonstrates your problem? With the Madrid theme, as it is included in the tex distributions, the title is not displayed  if using `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]`

Answer (score 1):

Just the first two lines you have is enough.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{document}
\title{Random}
\author{Dude}
\maketitle
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{abc}
dedf
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I find strange, from what i've seen I shouldn't have a footnote anymore. I have a modified Madrid thème, that I found on the internet. Don't know if it could change something
`\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{dove}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}`

Comment: @Rihannon So with the code above you *do* get the footer line? (It's not a `\footnote`, I'd guess.) If that is the case then you need to edit your question to include a link to that modified theme. (And a a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) wouldn't hurt either.)